# Javascript method synchronous call without callback and $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, synchronous, jquery-callback

Welcome,

I want to call synchronous javascript method without callbacks. 
The method is a POST asynchronous.

```
function someMethod() {
    var bean; //bean is a proxy object provide by external library
    if(clicked_onSpecial_field) {
        if(!bean.isAuthorized()) { //here is a async call
            return false;
        }  
    }

    //a lot of other instructions... 

}
```

From one hand usually `clicked_onSpecial_field = false` so I cannot put all other instructions in callback.
From the another hand `bean` is a provide to me proxy object. In this case i don't know in which way I can use `$.ajax`.

Could you please help?

Comment: How do you normally get the result back from bean.isAuthorized()? And can this result change based on things that happened earlier during the page usage?

Comment: It is a first time when i call this method. I prefer to check in every time because in theory authorization status can be changed in time. But thank you hidden suggestion to load this variable on page load :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to call synchronous javascript method without callbacks. The method is a POST asynchronous

If the method is inherently asynchronous, you cannot call it so that it returns synchronously. That's just outright impossible. See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572) for details.

> usually `clicked_onSpecial_field = false` so I cannot put all other instructions in callback.

Of course you can!

```
function someMethod() {
    var bean; //bean is a proxy object provide by external library
    if (clicked_onSpecial_field) {
        bean.isAuthorized(goOn); // pass goOn as callback
    } else {
        goOn(true); // just call it directly if there's no async action
    }

    function goOn(cond) {
        //a lot of other instructions... 
    }
}
```

Notice that `someMethod` is now asynchronous as well, so if you need to pass any results from it then you'd need to use a callback there as well.